# Android/Java: Multiple similar classes needing a super class, not sure where to start

Tags: java, android, class, subclass, superclass

Let's say I have 2 similar classes:

**Apple.java**

```
public class Apple {
    public string getFruitName(){
        return "apple";
    }
    public string getFruitColor(){
        return "red";
    }
}
```

**Banana.java**

```
public class Apple {
    public string getFruitName(){
        return "Banana";
    }
    public string getFruitColor(){
        return "yellow";
    }
}
```

In my application, I have a need for a global variable so I can dynamically generate a global scope banana or an apple anywhere. *The catch is*, I don't know which one of these is generated, it could be an apple, or a banana.

I'm *guessing* I need a superclass, maybe Fruit.java, and instantiate a global variable called fruit. When I call fruit.getFruitName and fruit.getFruitColor I would expect to be returned an apple or a banana, whichever was randomly generated. I just don't really know how to give all of these guys a parent class.

**Example of my application**

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
    Fruit fruit;

    ...

    public void randomFruit() {
        fruit = new Fruit();
    }

    public void sometimeLater() {
        if (fruit.getFruitName == "apple"){
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** Use the `.equals(...)` method to check for object equality, use `==` to check for primitive equality. `if(fruit.getFruitName == "apple")` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Just a note, there are no global variables or global scope in Java.  You can make things that are public but they will be associated with a class or object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface

```
interface Fruit {
    String getFruitName();
    String getFruitColor();
}
```

And then just implement it for both apple and banana

```
public class Apple implements Fruit {
    @Override
    public String getFruitName() {
        return "apple";
    }

    @Override
    public string getFruitColor() {
        return "red";
    }
}
```

And then you can assign banana or apple to `Fruit fruit` like this:

```
Fruit fruit = 
    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? new Apple() : new Banana();
```

I'd suggest you to read ["Inheritance" section of The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a super-class, you can make use of an interface to define `Fruit`:

interface Fruit {
        public string getName();
        public string getColor();
    }

```
public class Apple implements Fruit {
    public string getName() { return "Apple"; }
    public string getColor() { return "Red"; }
}

public class Banana implements Fruit {
    public string getName() { return "Banana"; }
    public string getColor() { return "Yellow"; }
}
```

You can then create a factory to generate a random piece of `Fruit`:

```
public static class FruitFarm {
    public static Fruit pick {
        return Math.random() > .5 ? new Apple() : new Banana();
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can simply call:

```
Fruit = FruitFarm.pick();
```

To get your random piece of fruit (and then call the methods to figure out which one you received).